# Ubuntu 16.04 Headphones not detected

Tags: sound, 16.04, headphones

I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 last night and when I tried to use sound today it didn't work.

I've tried all the things I can find online. Including force restarting pulseaudio and als, rebooting. Uninstalling and reinstalling pulseaudio. Editing my analog-output-headphones.conf. And some more I forgot (sorry) X D

My alsamixer settings are here
! [Alsamixer] (http://puu.sh/q5TAp.png)
[1] http://puu.sh/q5TAp.png